# Hypothesis testing with the weighted average of negative binomial distributions

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, negative-binomial

I am trying to do a statistical hypothesis testing between two random variables $Y^{(1)}$ and $Y^{(2)}$:

$Y^{(1)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^{(1)}X_i^{(1)}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{(1)}}$

$Y^{(2)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^{(2)}X_i^{(2)}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{(2)}}$

both of which are weighted average of a series of independent random variables $X_i$. Each $X_i$ is a negative binomial distribution with different but known parameters. All the weights $w_i$ are known.

Does anyone know what the distribution of $Y$ is?

Any ideas for the hypothesis testing?

Comment: Do you want to consider  the case when $n \to \infty$ or not?

Comment: No. n is a finite number.